# Add zero in front of single digit day in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have the following codes in visual basic that display the day/month/year

```
CStr(vDay) & "/" & (vMonth) & "/" & (vYear) & " " & (vHour) & ":" & (vMinute) & ":" &     (vSecond), DateTime.Now
```

How can I add a "0" in front of a single digit day and month?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your variables are integers, you can use the "D" format specifier to set how many digits you want, for instance:

```
vMonth.ToString("D2")
```

However, if you already have the value in a `Date` object, then you can just use it's built-in formatting, which would be easier:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 2):

To account for all situations, PadLeft is most helpful.
The first part is set total width for the integer, the second part is the character to be placed there.

```
vMonth.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0"c)
```

This would place a zero in front of single digit months.

Comment: For me this worked, not the accepted solution. Cool tx